# How Transfer the large database file from one server to another server?

Tags: mysql, database, import, export

I have a trouble with my database transfer from demo server to live server.,it's having the sql file size of 612 MB. I tried in different ways but i failed to import or transfer database to my live server.,if anybody having the solution for this means.,please guide me or instruct me As soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? What do you need help with? exporting? importing? both?

Comment: Do you have command line access on your server?

Comment: No i don't have the access for that

Comment: I removed the `mysqldump` tag from your question, it was misleading. I added `import` and `export` tags.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15802/discussion-between-john-peter-and-jocelyn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to do this , the best solution would be to use a dumper.

I use mysqldumper (http://www.mysqldumper.net/) , it does great job.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your quick response i'll try it and let you know

Comment: This is only use with export / backup right ? or it is use to import also ?

Comment: You use it to export from the original server , and then upload the file (via FTP) to the new server , install mysqldumper on new server , and then start importing.

Comment: Can you guide me with the steps to import after installing into new server.,what i need to do ?

Comment: 1.install the MySQLdumper in your new server (by upload to your server)..get the link (should be something like (yourdomaine.com/mysqldumper) 2.upload the backup you exported to the mysqldumper folder , and go to yourdomaine.com/mysqldumper , goto restore section and select the backup you upload and it will import it to new server

Comment: Sure Redhop i'll try it now.,i have successfully exported from my demo server.,thanks for your valuable suggestion.Now i'm going to import that.

Comment: This is great software!!! I had to move a 2GB db and it did it without much of a hiccup. Only issue was I FTPed the files into the wrong dir. That could be made clearer. FYI, they need to be put into the /mysqldumper/work/backup folder on the server you want to copy to.

Answer (score 2):

On your command prompt:

> mysqldump -h remote_server.com -uuser -psome_pawd database_name |
>   mysql -uuser - psome_pawd database_name

Here, the remote database dump is an input to the localhost which can be remote server too. So, server to server import and export happen here without using an intermediary file.

**Note:** If you wanna backup, u need to have an intermediary file

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350378/import-and-export-mysql-databases-without-using-an-intermediary-file/18350414#18350414)