# import remote database into localhost

Tags: mysql, import, export

I was figuring out how to import and export mysql databases without using an intermediary file .

Comment: I have edited the question. Please don't give a negative vote unless you provide the reason too. Just giving negative vote  doesn't serve the purpose

Answer (score 1):

Came ascross this:

> mysqldump -hremote_server.com -uuser -psome_pawd database_name | mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -   psome_pawd database_name

here, the `remote database dump is an input to the localhost` which can be remote server too.
So, server to server import and export happen here without  using an intermediary file.

Note:
If you wanna backup, u need to have an intermediary file